# Read data from ethernet on a docker container

Tags: docker, sockets, networking, docker-compose

What kind of configuration for docker do I need to read data from host's ethernet port inside a container? On the host machine (Ubuntu 20.04.4), I go to network -> Wired -> IPv4 Method, select Manual and set the static address and netmask from where I can receive the data via a socket. When running the code inside a docker container that is on the default network (so no configuration related to networking at all), I don't receive any data.

Comment: Do you need a `docker run -p` option?  What exactly are you trying to set up, and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to publish my port with UDP, like so:

```
ports:
- "50000:50000/udp"
```